# Put the .htaccess file and localhost become empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my URL for my website. `http://localhost/GASS-2110/alarm-system/overview.php`.I wanted to remove the .php extension so that the URL become like this;`http://localhost/GASS-2110/alarm-system/overview`. I  paste the .htaccess file in my root directory, run the localhost, and i find its empty! i dont know why is this happening and i am not sure what did i do wrong. I believed that i need to configure something which i do not know what it is.What am i suppose to do? I am a beginner so please dont be harsh with me. where should i call  the .htaccess file?

Here is what i put in my .htaccess  file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

p/s: sorry for my bad english

Comment: check apache error logs, looks like mod_rewrite is not enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a change in `.htaccess` results in the page being empty this means there was an error parsing the file, most frequently because of typos or referring to a module that's not loaded. You can check the problem in the Apache error log - check the `ErrorLog` directive in the vhost config for its location, otherwise it's in the general Apache error log (on Linux usually `/var/log/apache/error.log`).

If the error is something akin to `Unknown option RewriteEngine` you haven't enabled `mod_rewrite` correctly. On Debian/Ubuntu systems you can fix this by running `a2enmod rewrite`, for other systems the instructions could vary.